# Error trying to update document using autoForm with Schema in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

Error message:

> "Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty"

Using autoform with collection2 and simple schema in Meteor.
The schema:

```
Injuries = new Mongo.Collection('injuries');

Rehab = new SimpleSchema({
  exercise: {
    type: String,
    label: "Rehab Exercise"
  },
  sets: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Sets"
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Set Duration (in Minutes)"
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    label: "Date of Rehab Exercise"
  },
  rehabnotes: {
    type: String,
    label: "Notes: i.e. 70% Intensity During Sprints",
    max: 200
  },
  injuryid:{
    type: String,
  }
});

Injuries.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  player: {
    type: String,
    label: "Player",
    max: 50
  },
  injury: {
    type: String,
    label: "Injury"
  },
  notes: {
    type: String,
    label: "Notes",
    max: 200
  },
  injurydate: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Date of Injury",
  },
  rehab: {
    type: [Rehab],
    optional: true
  }
}));
```

And the Form Code in the Template:

```
 {{#autoForm collection="Injuries" schema="Rehab" id="insertRehabForm" type="update"}}
          <fieldset>

                {{> afQuickField name='exercise' options=options}}
                {{> afQuickField name='sets'}}
                {{> afQuickField name='duration'}}
                {{> afQuickField name='date'}}
                {{> afQuickField name='rehabnotes' rows=6}}

          </fieldset>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                {{/autoForm}}
```

I can insert documents just fine with the autoform on the home page, using this custom form on the individual document page I receive the error on submission.

I have one collection hook setup up for before submissions, but this looks like it is just a schema error, perhaps the `Rehab` array that I have set up on the original `Injuries` schema is messing this up? The searches I've done for this have all been about the "Type" parameter in the schema not matching what is expected, but I've checked those here and they look good. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the AutoForm's [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform-1): the `schema` attribute is required if `collection` attribute is not set, however, even if `collection` is set AutoForm will still use the provided `schema` attribute to *generate* (only applicable to QuickForm) and *validate* the form (applicable to both AutoForm and QuickForm).

What happened in your case is that since both attributes (`schema` and `collection`) are provided, AutoForm first validates the form fields against the `Rehab` schema and when it succeed, it **tries** to insert the values of those fields (exercise, sets, duration, date, rehabnotes) to your `Injuries` collection, which does not have those keys in its own schema (it only has player, injury, notes, injurydate and **rehab**).

From your requirements, it seems like setting the AutoForm type to `update-pushArray` is the best possible solution. Check the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#update-pusharray) and the [example](http://autoform.meteor.com/updatepush) for usage.